# SQL Azure Serverless configuration problem

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Up to this point I have been using the "Basic" tier of SQL Azure and the price is around £7/month. This time of year my database doesn't get any traffic and so I would like to pause it - which can't be done on this tier. I need to scale to Serverless.

I've selected

- Serverless
- Hardware: Gen5
- Max vCores: 4
- Min vCores: 4
- Auto Pause: 1 hour

This morning when I woke up, I received an alert that my bill has exceeded £58 and will be projected as £158 for months end.

What am I missing here? When I toggle the settings the cost projection comes nowhere near that and with the auto-pause set the price should be next to nothing? If the price is £7 with Basic, I'd be expecting the ad-hoc provisioning to be much less. Is there something else I need to toggle?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 purchace models for Azure SQL "vcore" and "DTU"

From the info that you have given it looks like you have choosen "vcore".

The minimum cost would be single database, DTU, Basic with 5 DTU, then you would pay ca. GBP 4 per month

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/single/

Answer (score 0):

Autopausing is triggered if all of the following conditions are true for the duration of the autopause delay:

- Number sessions = 0
- CPU = 0 for user workload running in the user pool

The following features do not support autopausing If any of the following features are used, then autopausing should be disabled and the database will remain online regardless of the duration of database inactivity:

- Geo-replication (active geo-replication and auto-failover groups).
- Long-term backup retention (LTR).
- The sync database used in SQL data sync. Unlike sync databases, hub and member databases support autopausing.
- DNS aliasing
- The job database used in Elastic Jobs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview

In your case it seems that auto-pause setting does not actually turn off the Azure SQL Database serverless completely, if you check the Query Performance Insight menu option and see actual queries being run, you will find some queries or activities that prevents Azure SQL Database serverless to go sleep

Running queries in the Query Performance Insights tab also wakes up a paused database, so be careful when using that tool.

Comment: I don't have any of those activated. When I select "Configure" on the Database and Select Serverless I see the options for my vCores. On the right of the screen it shows a cost estimation starting at 0.25pence/month. When I slide the Cores up to the maximum on both max/min the cost projection doesn't change. It stays at 0.25p :(

Comment: Do you see any activities in Query Performance Insights?

Comment: From yesterday at 2pm until now (10 hours later) it slept for 4 hours solid. Then it woke up to do a small query than runs for 9ms and executed this several times in the last few hours. The price for the work it's doing - which is a Select Top 1- seems really disproportionate.

Comment: So you can calculate approximate billing. As I understood your SQL DB was sleeping for 4 hours and was active for 6 hours 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=sql-database